# How do I do a cron job with cyclical argument?

Tags: shell-script, cron

I want to run a bash script say every 5 minutes, with a predefined argument according to a cycle.

For example, I want to use as the argument 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 50, 15, 10, 5, 2, and then start the cycle again.

Ideally, the arguments are stored in a file or in the script where I can easily edit them, add or remove some, etc.

How do I do that ?

---

I could do it with a single script, an array and a `while [[ true ]]` but I'd like to know if I can do that with cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most effective and one of the more simpler ways to accomplish this would be to have the script handle keeping track of cycling the magic number rather than using arguments.  Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sequence=(1 2 5 10 15 50 15 10 5 2)
if [[ -r /var/tmp/myjob.seq ]]; then
   seq="$(cat /var/tmp/myjob.seq)"
   if [[ $seq -lt $((${#sequence[@]}-1)) ]]; then
       nextseq=$(($seq+1))
   else
       nextseq=0
   fi
   echo $nextseq > /var/tmp/myjob.seq
else
   seq=0
   echo 1 > /var/tmp/myjob.seq
fi
magicnumber=${sequence[$seq]}
```

You can then refer to `$magicnumber` later on in the script, and use whatever cron schedule you like.

Comment: I agree with DopeGhoti here, but I have to note that if you ever want to accomplish what the script does, you'll have to have a version that does not check the sequence. If you just run the script you may not get what you want, and it can be puzzling and painful to figure out.

Comment: On the other hand, if the script is manually run, you can just set the sequence by writing to the canary file in `/var/tmp` before execution, or after it to reset it to its previous state.

Comment: I guarantee you I would forget to do that, then spend 15 minutes trying to figure out what went wrong. My cron job checked if it was running on the 2nd Saturday of the month, and I was so puzzled when it wasn't working. You are probably smarter than me, and won't face this.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thanks for the answer. I'm a little new to this and it doesn't seem to do what I want. When I run it manually (after I added `echo $magicnumber` at the end), I get 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, ... etc. I don't know what I'm supposed to write in the "canary file", I'm sorry I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: What is `if [[ $seq -lt ${#seq} ]]` supposed to do ? I'm assuming it's normal behaviour, when the end of the sequence isn't reached yet but I don't see how it would do that. `${#seq}` returns the number of characters in `$seq`, right ?

Comment: Ooooh I see you probably meant the length of the sequence, not `$seq`. So it should be `${#sequence[@]}` instead of $seq. Then you need to substract 1, because there are 10 elements, so so index goes from 0 to 9 : `$((${#sequence[@]}-1))`. I found another error, the `echo $nextseq > /var/tmp/myjob.seq` doesn't get executed if the `else` isn't reached. You have to move the `fi`up one line, indentation isn't enough. It seems to work now :)

Comment: Yep, was exactly my intent.  Apologies for the error.